# Is this an efficient way of finding and assigning the owner of a window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, owner

This is the way I do it now, but I'm not sure if it's inefficient, since the runtime is O(n):

```
foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (window.GetType() == typeof(TransactionsWindow))
    {
        this.Owner = window;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make it constant or a more effective way than what I'm doing?  Basically, I'm trying to confirm if I'm doing it the right way -- always trying to improve.  The window gets opened by a button event, so I'm wondering if there's a way to find out which window the event was called from and assign that window as the owner, rather than having to search through all the open windows and hard coding the owner type.

Comment: Or just write `Owner = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<TransactionsWindow>().FirstOrDefault();`.

Comment: Wow!  That is definitely shorter than writing foreach loop with `break;` in it.  Linq is amazing.

Comment: Using this is generally poor practice, but not for performance reasons, but rather because it creates brittle code.

Comment: @Servy  Which one, the code I posted or Clemens?  And what do you mean by "brittle code" ?

Comment: @Noobacode Both; the use of `Application.Current.Windows` in general.  Conceptually you're simply trying to make up for the fact that you "lost track" of the window's proper owner by looking through all of the windows.  The owner should have been set when it was created, rather than wherever this is.

Comment: @Servy I understand.  That's exactly what Robert Levy suggested.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine.  If you have enough windows open that O(N) here is an issue, your actual problem is much bigger than this loop.

That said, you might as well put a `break;` inside the `if`.  Also, it would probably be better architecture for the windows doing `theTransactionsWindow.Show()` to also set `theTransactionsWindow.Owner = this`

Comment: Hmm, you're right... I didn't think about that.  For some reason I was thinking that it goes through all the application windows.  Instead, it's the currently open windows.  I even mentioned that it's the open windows in original post... need more coffee.

Comment: `break;` is an excellent idea.  As far as the .owner = this.... do you mean that the window that's trying to display this window is the one that should set its owner, rather than me trying to set it in the code-behind of the window itself?

Comment: yes, it would be more efficient for the owner to set itself as the owner directly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through windows, it might be a cleaner solution to use the Source property [RoutedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) variable in your button click event to find the *actual* button that made the call, and then the window owner of that button.  Something like below:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = e.Source as Button;
        if (btn == null)
            return;

        Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(btn);
        this.Owner = parentWindow;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that set the window as its own parent?

Comment: It would be whichever window the event was called from, which is what I thought your question said you were looking for, my apologies if I misunderstood